# Sending HTTP command in browser works, not when sent with httppost

Tags: java, http-post-vars

When in my browser I send the following string to a control unit I have `http://192.168.0.215/i_activate/aterm?40~00` and a relay is activated.

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.215/i_activate/aterm?40~00");

// Execute HTTP Post Request            
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

With an HTML response "FAIL" from the unit

I have tried adding the 40~00 in many ways (NameValuePair, etc) and encoded in different forms without success but I am sure the problem lies there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Very that both the browser and your software are sending the same thing - see `wireshark` for a protocol snooper that will show you exactly what's being sent.  (Or look at the log for your webserver)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd recommend fiddler over WireShark if you are using a modern web-browser. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the browser sends a `GET` request, where the parameter is in the URL itself as a query string, but you are sending a `POST` request without any body data.

Use `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost` to send a `GET` request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.215/i_activate/aterm?40~00");

// Execute HTTP Get Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: Can you include the proper format for an http-post for myself an other users knowledge?  Thanks for answering.